# Is it possible to install third-party apps on Xiaomi Wear-Os (Redmi Watch 2 Lite)?

Tags: flutter, wear-os, watch, xiaomi

I need Xiaomi Redmi Watch 2 support developer mode, or can I install third-party apps on it or not. I'm trying to test a flutter wear os app on my watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Xiaomi Redmi watches use a proprietary OS other than Android. So, unfortunately, Flutter doesn't support it (yet).